# Display loop data in sorted manner

Tags: php, sorting, curl

I want to display `<li>` where, I am having issue with my loop, see my code below

```
<?php
  for ($j=0;$j<$task_count;$j++)
  {
    $task_name = $task[$j]['summary'];
    $summary_length = strlen('');
    $task_id = $task[$j]['_id'];
    $task_status = $task[$j]['status'];
    $summary_count = strlen($task_name);
    if ($task_name=='task') {
          $final_task_summary =  $task_id ;
    }
    elseif($summary_count <= 50)
    {
      $final_task_summary = $task_name;
    }
    else
    {
        $final_task_summary = mb_substr($task_name, 0, 50);

    }
?>
```

Here, I want to display `<li> </li>` in order where first it shows `<li>` having status "open" then "resolved" and then "close" and only 20 `<li>` should take place.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to:

- Print list items for the first 20 items.
- Printing should be done ordered based on status.

If you're getting the data from a database, then it would be better to handle this in the query, If not, you can do as follows.

1. Change your loop to get only 20 items instead of task count
2. Declare three strings to hold li items for each status.
3. Within the loop, Check for the status and append the desired string with li items.
4. After the loop, print the three strings in the required order.

Let me know if anything needs clarification.
Thanks,

Comment: No, i dont want first 20 items i need to display 20 from all the data and first it should display items which are having status "Open, then having resolved ,and then  closed".